Metallic bonds in Copper and Electric field application
Didnt know where to put this since its like a combination of Chemistry and Physics.
But in the picture below, we can see that they've defined a metallic bond as essentially the attraction between the net positive charge on a copper ion due to its valence electron promotion into conduction band. Firstly, i think the image depicts an inaccurate representation of the number of localized electrons. If each Copper atom only has 1 valence electron, how is it possible to see some many in the image? Anyway, lets say if we were to apply an electric field across copper. Would the delocalised electrons move in the direction of the field to create a charge separation? If so, wouldn't this weaken the structure of copper? Or does the copper ion remain intact with its +1 net charge by attracting the electrons of other copper ions, in the 2nd most outer shell/new valence shell?


We could assume that more copper ions are lined up exactly behind the ones we see, whereas the electrons are more scattered so we see more of them! The electrons would of course move against the direction of the field. (And apart from long-term electromigration effects it would not weaken the structure). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration (PS: it would become a more interesting question for metallic hydrogen where there are no inner shells!)

Okay thank for that, it explains the movement of ions due to momentum of electrons. But why is the structure not weakened if the electrons are responsible for holding together the ions?

That is the "stability of matter" question. Perhaps any of these can help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=stability+of+matter
(And of course metallic hydrogen would still be an interesting case to start with!))

Start at T = 0 K with no electron promotion. Metal atoms form metallic bonds. Consider metallic bonds as covalent bonds with one distinction ... each electron in any given metallic bond is shared cooperatively across all atoms. No one atom has a net negative or net positive charge. All valence electrons are in bound molecular orbital states in the valence band to the metal, and all metal atoms share all the bound electrons in the valence band.
Raise the temperature. Electrons are promoted from the valence state to the conduction band, crossing the Fermi energy. As an electron is promoted in energy out of its bound valence band state, it leaves behind an empty state at its starting energy. The empty state is called a hole. In the same respect that the bound electron was initially shared by all metal atoms, so too is the hole that is left behind shared by all metal atoms. The hole is delocalized.
The free electron has been moved to a state that is no longer a bound state. It is free to respond to a voltage field. It can carry current.
The bound hole could also respond to a voltage field. However, in a metal, the bound hole is delocalized. So, the bound hole has no sense of a direction to go when a field is applied. It does not carry current.
The opposite applies to semiconductors. When the hole is created in the covalent bound between two semiconductor (metalloid) atoms, the hole is localized. It can and does respond to the force of an applied field.
In summary, in metals, individual atoms do not become locally charged in a partial positive or negative way. Metallic bonding should therefore not be pictured as a case of a sea of valence or conduction electrons holding together positively charged metal ions.
